# PHP form + REPLACE INTO mySQL isn't working, but an identical query on another page is functional.. is there something I'm missing?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

As the title implies, I have been trying to solve where my issue resides but I have come up empty handed. It does not make any sense to me. I am using a near **IDENTICAL** `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` elsewhere in my wordpress site but for some reason, this one is causing me a headache, and continuously giving me 404 errors when I press the submit button.

My connection to my database is unchanged either (I just changed them in my code below for security reasons).

Lastly - I know I have no action in the `form` - that is because the action is within the php page. I have it set up like this on another page with fewer `<input>` and it works just fine.

I have a feeling I am overlooking something super simple but it is eating me away for the past couple days!
Here is my table structure (from Adminer);

```
Column          Type    
coin            varchar(11)  
address         varchar(50)  
name            varchar(50)  
serverip        varchar(20)  
port            char(10) [0]     
explorer        char(90)     
api_getbalance  char(90)     
balance         int(40) [0]  
collateral      int(20)  
earning         char(30) [0]     
status          char(15) [ENABLED]
```

And I have set the `Primary Key` to `address` since the REPLACE function requires a Primary/Unique Key set.

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'product',);
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$coin = $_POST['coin'];
$serverip = $_POST['serverip'];
$port = $_POST['port'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$explorer = $_POST['explorer'];
$apigetbalance = $_POST['apigetbalance'];
$collateral = $_POST['collateral'];

$con2 = mysqli_connect("IP","USER","PASS","DB");

$update = "REPLACE INTO wp_shared_nodes (address, name, serverip, port, coin, explorer, api_getbalance, collateral) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con2,$update);

if ($stmt) {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssss', $address, $name, $serverip, $port, $coin, $explorer, $apigetbalance, $collateral);

  $ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

  if ($ok) {
    echo "<strong> <i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i> The node information was added correctly.</strong>";
  } else {
    echo 'Data Not Updated';
    error_log(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
  }

  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} else {
  error_log(mysqli_error($con2));
}

mysqli_close($con2);
}
?>
<?php   
echo "<p><h5>Add/Change Node:</h5>";

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<form method = "post">';
echo '<div class="row"><div class="column">';

//coin name
echo '<p style="margins:0"><h5>Coin Name</h5>';
echo '<p><input type="text" placeholder="Insert Coin Name" id="name" name="name" size="40" /></p>';

//coin ticker
echo '<p style="margins:0"><h5>Ticker</h5>';  
echo '<p><select id="coin" name="coin">';
    echo '<option>-- Select coin--</option>';
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  global $product;
    echo '<option value=' . $product->get_sku() . '>' . $product->get_sku() . ' </option>';
  endwhile;
echo '</select>';  

//wallet address
echo '<p style="margins:0"><h5>Wallet Address</h5>';
echo '<p><input type="text" placeholder="Address" id="address" name="address" size="40" /></p>';  

//Collateral
echo '<p style="margins:0"><h5>Collateral</h5>';
echo '<p><input type="text" placeholder="Amount" id="collateral" name="collateral" size="10" /></p>';  

echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="column">';

//Server IP
echo '<p style="margins:0"><h5>Server IP</h5>';
echo '<p><input type="text" placeholder="IP Address" id="serverip" name="serverip" size="20" /></p>'; 

//Server Port
echo '<p style="margins:0"><h5>Port</h5>';
echo '<p><input type="text" placeholder="Port" id="port" name="port" size="10" /></p>';   

//Explorer
echo '<p style="margins:0"><h5>Explorer link to default address</h5>';
echo '<p><input type="text" placeholder="e.g. https://explore.creativecoin.design/address/" id="explorer" name="explorer" size="50" /></p>';

//Ext/getbalance
echo '<p style="margins:0"><h5>API link for balance</h5>';
echo '<p><input type="text" placeholder="e.g. https://explore.creativecoin.design/ext/getbalance/" id="apigetbalance" name="apigetbalance" size="50" /></p>';

echo '</div></div>';

echo '<br><input type="submit" name="submit">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: Close your submit input tag?

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment, not an answer, but I don't have enough points yet to comment.

I feel the problem is likely in your "action" for the form. Since it's not in your code, I can't test it. But, it's the action that determines which page gets posted to when you submit. Since you're getting a 404 error, that would imply that you've set the action to a page that doesn't exist or you've used the wrong path. If the error were in your function, you'd get to the right page, so no 404, and then you'd get sql or php errors or unexpected results, but not a 404.

I created a very simple test page, using your exact submit input, and it works as I'd expect:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                echo "submit isset";
            } else {
                echo "submit !isset";
            }
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you'd like to post the "action" statement, I might be able to figure out what is wrong with it, but, it may be as simple as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error is an `HTTP` status code that means that the page you were trying to reach on a website couldn't be found on their server.

```
    <p><h5>Add/Change Node:</h5>
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <form action="submit.php" method = "post">

<div class="row"><div class="column">

//coin name
<p style="margins:0"><h5>Coin Name</h5>`<br>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Insert Coin Name" id="name" name="name" size="40" /></p>    
//coin ticker
<p style="margins:0"><h5>Ticker</h5> 
<p><select id="coin" name="coin">
<option>-- Select coin--</option>
<? php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
 global $product;
    echo '<option value=' . $product->get_sku() . '>' . $product->get_sku() . ' </option>';
  endwhile;
?>
</select>

//wallet address
<p style="margins:0"><h5>Wallet Address</h5>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Address" id="address" name="address" size="40" /></p> 

 //Collateral
 <p style="margins:0"><h5>Collateral</h5>
 <p><input type="text" placeholder="Amount" id="collateral" name="collateral" 
  size="10" /></p>

</div> 
<div class="column">

//Server IP
<p style="margins:0"><h5>Server IP</h5>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="IP Address" id="serverip" name="serverip" 
 size="20" /></p>

//Server Port`<br>
<p style="margins:0"><h5>Port</h5>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Port" id="port" name="port" size="10" /> 
</p>

//Explorer
<p style="margins:0"><h5>Explorer link to default address</h5>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="e.g. https://explore.creativecoin.design/address/" id="explorer" name="explorer" size="50" /></p>

//Ext/getbalance
<p style="margins:0"><h5>API link for balance</h5>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="e.g. https://explore.creativecoin.design/ext/getbalance/" id="apigetbalance" name="apigetbalance" size="50" /></p>

</div></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**form action is needed thats why its show 404 error**
you may also try

```
action=""
action="same page url"
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).